# Java | Checking Bounds of Matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I'm attempting to do a simple check to make sure the row and column supplied by the client is in bounds of the matrix's array. However I keep getting a

Failed: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Tester:

```
  public void testBoundsForGet() {  // m is a 4x3 matrix
        try {
            m.get(-1, 2);
            fail("get should not have succeeded");
        }
        catch(MatrixException ex) {
            assertTrue(ex.getMessage().equals("Row index (-1) out of bounds"));
        }
```

Check Bounds Method:

```
 protected void checkBounds(int row, int column) {
         if((this.numRows < row) || (row < 0)){
             throw new MatrixException(String.format("The row (%s) is out of range", row));
         }

         if((this.numColumns < column) || (column < 0)){
             throw new MatrixException(String.format("The column (%s) is out of range", column));
         }

    }
```

Comment: The exception you're throwing says `The row (-1) is out of range`, but you're writing an assertion to check that it says `Row index (-1) out of bounds`

Comment: Adding to Stik's comment: i would also switch to assertEquals to check the string equality. It has the benefit of showing you what it expected and what it got instead of just giving you true/false

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm in class right now but will post my fix after.

Comment: Both are wrong.  You should not be checking the message; you should indicate that you expect an exception to be thrown.  The test that I wrote is the proper idiom for JUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @duffymo, I'll try to implement yours, I know nothing about JUnit or proper form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd want to see four tests in total: one each for row and column less than the min value of 0 and above the max value for the matrix in question.  I'd write those tests as follows:

```
@Test(expected = MatrixException.class)
public void testCheckBounds_NegativeRow() {  // m is a 4x3 matrix
    // You must have defined m somewhere else as a member variable.
    m.get(-1, 2);
}

@Test(expected = MatrixException.class)
public void testCheckBounds_LargerThanMaxRow() {  // m is a 4x3 matrix
    // You must have defined m somewhere else as a member variable.
    m.get(10, 2);
}

@Test(expected = MatrixException.class)
public void testCheckBounds_NegativeColumn() {  // m is a 4x3 matrix
    // You must have defined m somewhere else as a member variable.
    m.get(1, -2);
}

@Test(expected = MatrixException.class)
public void testCheckBounds_LargerThanMaxColumn() {  // m is a 4x3 matrix
    // You must have defined m somewhere else as a member variable.
    m.get(1, 20);
}

@Test
public void testCheckBounds_Success() {
    // what should you asset here?  It's not a useful method.  I'd return boolean
    m.get(1,1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the person who voted this down was ignorant of the proper idiom for JUnit.